# WMI Permanent Events

Tags: powershell, events, wmi

I try to set wmi permanent events base on specifics events coming from network card on a Windows 7 SP1.

I use this code:

```
    #Creating a new event filter
$instanceFilter = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:__EventFilter").CreateInstance()
$instanceFilter.QueryLanguage = "WQL"
$instanceFilter.Query = "Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent' AND TargetInstance.LogFile='System' AND TargetInstance.SourceName LIKE '%e1_express%' AND (TargetInstance.EventCode=27 OR TargetInstance.EventCode=32 OR TargetInstance.EventCode=33 OR TargetInstance.EventCode=36)"
$instanceFilter.Name = "LAN_Watcher_Filter"
$instanceFilter.EventNamespace = 'root\cimv2'
$result = $instanceFilter.Put()
$newFilter = $result.Path


#Creating a new event consumer

$instanceConsumer = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer").CreateInstance()
$instanceConsumer.Name ='LAN_Watcher_Consumer'
$instanceConsumer.ExecutablePath="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$instanceConsumer.CommandLineTemplate="-file C:\Windows\System32\Switch_LAN_TEST.ps1"
$result = $instanceConsumer.Put()
$newConsumer = $result.Path


#Bind filter and consumer
$instanceBinding = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:__FilterToConsumerBinding").CreateInstance()
$instanceBinding.Filter = $newFilter
$instanceBinding.Consumer = $newConsumer
$result = $instanceBinding.Put()
$newBinding = $result.Path


##Removing WMI Subscriptions using [wmi] and Delete() Method
#([wmi]$newFilter).Delete()
#([wmi]$newConsumer).Delete()
#([wmi]$newBinding).Delete()
```

I can turn off the powershell session, script will be launch but if I reboot the computer, the permanent event exist again but the script doesn't work.

Any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: I checked my script on a Windows 10, it works fine even after a reboot.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Show output, expectations, etc.

Comment: The script is not called by the permanent event.
I have no output or error.

Comment: Maybe Windows 7 require something else

Comment: Have you found any more informaiton on this? I'm creating a permanenent event subscription like this, it works after I create it, but when I reboot, it's still there but doesn't trigger anymore. I'm on latest Windows 10.

Comment: I just found the reason it wasn't working after reboot for me, it's extremely important the creatorSID is a local admin see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/receiving-events-securely#sids-and-permanent-subscriptions