# WMI event subscription using [wmiclass] not working in Powershell Core

Tags: powershell, wmi

I've been trying to get code below running in Powershell Core for many hours, but it doesn't work. I need something like that if one program starts ( say regedit) it triggers another program to start, say notepad. (Note: I need to do this with code below, so not Register-WMIEvent and friends)
The code below is btw found somewhere found on internet. It works in another example like can be found here  https://learn-powershell.net/page/33/ where 'consumer' is LogFileEventConsumer, but not in the code I try where 'consumer' is CommandLineEventConsumer.

I googled for many hours and read maybe it had to do something with 'CreatorSid', but I tried many things and I'm out of ideas.
Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any hints.

Code:

```sh
#Creating a new event filter
$instanceFilter = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:__EventFilter").CreateInstance()

$instanceFilter.QueryLanguage = "WQL"
$instanceFilter.Query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 3 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name='regedit.exe'"
$instanceFilter.Name = $sourceIdentifier
$instanceFilter.EventNamespace = 'root\cimv2'
#[byte[]] $instanceFilter.CreatorSid = 1,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,32,0,0,0,32,2,0,0

$result = $instanceFilter.Put()
$newFilter = $result.Path

#Creating a new event consumer
$instanceConsumer = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer").CreateInstance()

$instanceConsumer.Name = 'Somename'
$instanceConsumer.CommandLineTemplate = "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
#[byte[]] $instanceConsumer.CreatorSid =  1,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,32,0,0,0,32,2,0,0

$result = $instanceConsumer.Put()
$newConsumer = $result.Path

#Bind filter and consumer
$instanceBinding = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:__FilterToConsumerBinding").CreateInstance()

$instanceBinding.Filter = $newFilter 
$instanceBinding.Consumer = $newConsumer
#[byte[]] $instanceBinding.CreatorSid =  1,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,32,0,0,0,32,2,0,0

$result = $instanceBinding.Put()
$newBinding = $result.Path

##Removing WMI Subscriptions using [wmi] and Delete() Method
#([wmi]$newFilter).Delete()
#([wmi]$newConsumer).Delete()
#([wmi]$newBinding).Delete()
```

Comment: What happens when you try with `CommandLineEventConsumer`? Does it throw an error? And what leads you to believe "maybe it had to do something with 'CreatorSid'"? :)

Comment: Hi, I guess you mean change this "$instanceConsumer.Name = 'Somename'" into 
"$instanceConsumer.Name = 'CommandLineEventconsumer'"? That doesn`t work either. About the CreatorSid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292373/wmi-permanent-events led me to this thought.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does the filter get created? What about the consumer instance and the binding? Is an error thrown? Does the computer catch on fire?

Comment: Hi, nothing happens... No error is thrown, but notepad is not fired up as I would expect.

Comment: Actually I found the script does start notepad, but it`s not "visible" as it`s started as service (??) in "session 0". This is what tasklist says:                                                                    PS C:\Users\Administrator> tasklist.exe

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============

notepad.exe                   1048 Services                   0      3,624 K
tasklist.exe                  1252 Console                    1      5,132 K

Comment: Anyone know a way to solve the above problem?