Can not run ps1 as script
i wanna run the following script as ps1, if i copy and paste it on powershell as admin, it works fine, but as ps1 it does not show any error but does not function either:
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force
# We will write events to the Windows Application log with source name of CheckUSB
If (-not [System.Diagnostics.Eventlog]::SourceExists('CheckHard')) {
    # Event log source does not exist, so we create it
    New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source 'CheckHard'
}

# Unregister this event only
Unregister-Event RemovableHardDetection -Force

# Define the WMI query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA ''Win32_DiskDrive'''

# Define the action to be performed when the event is triggered
$action = {
    $strUSBSerialFilename = 'C:\usbcontrol\usb_serial.json'
    $strClass = $eventArgs.NewEvent.__CLASS
    $strPNPdeviceID = $eventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.PNPDeviceID
    $arraySplitPNPdeviceID = $strPNPdeviceID.split('\')
    $strConnectedUSBSerial = $arraySplitPNPdeviceID[-1]
    $strlogfile = 'C:\usbcontrol\usbcontrol.log'
    $strdatetime = Get-Date
    $strdatetime = $strdatetime.GetDateTimeFormats()[19]

    function Read-approved-USB($strFileWithPath) {
        if (Test-Path $strFileWithPath) {
            $tempObj = $null 
            try {   
                $tempObj = Get-Content -Raw -Path $strFileWithPath | ConvertFrom-Json
                Write-Output $tempObj # Return PowerShell representation of JSON file back. Must have this line.  
            }
            catch {
                $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
                $strMessageToSend = " [$strdatetime] Error: $ErrorMessage for $FailedItem"
                Write-Host " $strMessageToSend "
                Write-Output " $strMessageToSend " | Out-File $strlogfile -Append
                Write-Error $StrMessageToSend -ErrorAction Stop
            }
        }
    }

    function Check-for-approved-USB($strSerialFileName, $strConUSBSerial) {
        $IntReturnValue = 0
        $objSerials = Read-approved-USB $strSerialFileName
        $objSerials.ValidSerialNumbers | foreach {
            $ApprovedSN = $_
            if ($ApprovedSN.USBSerial -eq $strConUSBSerial) {        
                # The USB serial is on the approved list, indicate that by setting IntReturnValue to 1
                $IntReturnValue = 1
                $strMessageToSend = "USB [$strdatetime] JSON value: " + $ApprovedSN.USBSerial + " Equals " +  $USBSerialNumber
                Write-Host "$strMessageToSend"
                Write-Output "$strMessageToSend " | Out-File $strlogfile -Append
            }
            else {
                $strMessageToSend = "USB  [$strdatetime] JSON value: " + $ApprovedSN.USBSerial + " Not equals " +  $USBSerialNumber
                Write-Host " $strMessageToSend"  
                Write-Output "$strMessageToSend " | Out-File $strlogfile -Append
            }
        }
        Write-Output $IntReturnValue
    }

    # Switch based on event class
    switch ($strClass) {
        __InstanceCreationEvent {
            $intApprovedUSB = 0
            Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $strPNPdeviceID -Confirm:$false
            $intApprovedUSB = Check-for-approved-USB $strUSBSerialFilename $strConnectedUSBSerial
            $strMessageToSend = "HARD DISK [$strdatetime] Insertion event for $strPNPdeviceID. Check if approved returned: $intApprovedUSB"
            Write-Host $strMessageToSend
            Write-Output " $strMessageToSend " | Out-File $strlogfile -Append
            if ($intApprovedUSB -eq 1) {
                $strMessageToSend = "USB [$strdatetime] Inserted, device id: $strPNPdeviceID with serial: $strConnectedUSBSerial on approved list."
                Write-Host $strMessageToSend 
                Write-Output " $strMessageToSend " | Out-File $strlogfile -Append
                Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $strPNPdeviceID -Confirm:$false
            }
            else {
                $strMessageToSend = "HARD DISK [$strdatetime] Inserted, device id: $strPNPdeviceID with serial: $strConnectedUSBSerial not on approved list."
                Write-Host $strMessageToSend
                Write-Output "$strMessageToSend " | Out-File $strlogfile -Append
            }
        }

        __InstanceDeletionEvent {
            $strMessageToSend = "USB [$strdatetime] Removed, device id: $strPNPdeviceID with serial: $strConnectedUSBSerial"
            Write-Host $strMessageToSend
            Write-Output " $strMessageToSend " | Out-File $strlogfile -Append
        }

        __InstanceModificationEvent {
            $intApprovedUSB = 0
            Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $strPNPdeviceID -Confirm:$false
            $intApprovedUSB = Check-for-approved-USB $strUSBSerialFilename $strConnectedUSBSerial
            $strMessageToSend = "USB [$strdatetime] Modification event for $strPNPdeviceID. Check if approved returned: $intApprovedUSB"
            Write-Host $strMessageToSend
            Write-Output " $strMessageToSend " | Out-File $strlogfile -Append
            if ($intApprovedUSB -eq 1) {
                $strMessageToSend = "USB [$strdatetime] Inserted, device id: $strPNPdeviceID with serial: $strConnectedUSBSerial on approved list."
                Write-Host $strMessageToSend 
                Write-Output " $strMessageToSend " | Out-File $strlogfile -Append
                Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $strPNPdeviceID -Confirm:$false
            }
            else {
                $strMessageToSend = "USB [$strdatetime] Inserted, device id: $strPNPdeviceID with serial: $strConnectedUSBSerial not on approved list."
                Write-Host $strMessageToSend
                Write-Output " $strMessageToSend " | Out-File $strlogfile -Append
            }
        }
    }
}

# Register the WMI event
Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier RemovableHardDetection -Action $action -ComputerName $ENV:COMPUTERNAME

it is a code to detect Hard Disk insertion and after insertion it disables it if its id is not found from white-list, when i copy and paste it to powershell it works totally fine, but when i close the console, it stops working.
I want it keep running untill poweroff, coz i am gonna execute it on every start-up with task-scheduler.
Please help me with it, i have been trying for almost a week now

How are you attempting to run it as a script? You launch powershell.exe as admin, enter the path to the script and hit Enter?

Like mentioned above if you just run this as powershell.exe if you close the shell it stops running. You may have to shove this into a windows background process

Register-WmiEvent only creates a subscriber for that powershell session, so it's gone once the powershell window closes. For a more permanent solution, you might want to create a CommandLineEventConsumer like in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31292373/7411885

i am running it like right click and "run with powershell"

about CommandLineEventConsumer i dont know yet, first let me study it first
